# Get-process property to show its begun

Tags: powershell

Have 3 questions here

1. Is using True of False statement to show command finsihed I know $?
   does this but can I have it in 1 line ie "Get-Process | Get-Member
   $?"
2. Which get-process property will show a process started and is this
   the same to use with New-Timespan ?
3. How can I use get help to see these variables for Get-Process and New-Timespan?

Comment: Question 1 - Makes no sense. `$?` tells you whether the preceding command succeeded or failed. What are you trying to do? Question 2 - The `StartTime` property of the process object tells you when it was started. Question 3 - Variables aren't properties, and properties can be objects. It sounds like you need to learn some PowerShell fundamentals, and this will all be less confusing.

Comment: Thanks Stewart, ye the course is on it 4th class and seems to have taken a jump this class I will be looking for some learning videos if you have any suggestions. but I have to Get-Process object pipe it to Get_Member and then asked what method gives a true/false valeu to indicate is finished. This lab has been all about you finding the answer from the Get-Help section

Comment: I think we may have a language barrier, as I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to get help with a class that you are taking. There is nothing wrong with doing that on stackoverflow as long as you are open about it. However this is a programming help website. If you have specific code that you have written that you are having problems with, please post that code and ask questions about the code.

Comment: Also, it sounds like you need to spend some time understanding the differences between a variable, object, cmdlet, and property.

Comment: Ok ye, I'm not hiding the fact that i'm in college, But that's fine and I know cmdlets but variable and objects are slightly confusing I would still treat variables like they were in Linux like this command that im asking about "$promem = Get-Process | Get-Member"  $promem is my named variable, everything after the = is the variables value. but this $promem is also considered an object ye? but my question was how to have that command output a true or false statement when the command finishes

Answer (score 0):

As an IT/Dev educator myself I see this sort of confusion all the time with students in sessions. Primarily, because of preconceived ideas, or they may have bitten off more that they thought, or they really just don't get it.

I am not real sure which camp you'd gravitate to, but, here's some edification for you (at least I hope so) based on all you have said and how the others have been trying to guide you.

> 1. Is using True of False statement to show command finsihed I know $? 
>      does this but can I have it in 1 line ie "Get-Process | Get-Member $?"

No, because these are separate things. Get-Process brings back a collection of all running processes. You cannot use Get-Member on a collection. You use it on a single object.

```
Get-Process | Get-Member $?
```

will return nothing, because you have not told it what process object of the collection you want to examine.

```
Get-Process 


Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
    462      27    19756      35460       1.47   9592   1 ApplicationFrameHost
    149       9     1584       6800       0.02   5344   0 armsvc
    298      20    15020      21048   1,312.03   8496   0 audiodg
    484      26    15712      35924       0.38  17584   1 Calculator
    ...
```

vs

```
(Get-Process)[0] # Collections and arrays are zero-based

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
    462      27    19756      35460       1.47   9592   1 ApplicationFrameHost
```

Or

```
Get-Process | Select-Object -First 1


Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
    462      27    19756      35460       1.47   9592   1 ApplicationFrameHost
```

The $? is just returning True or false, if the *'last command issued'* completed successfully or not, not anything before it.

```
# Start a specific process
Start-Process -FilePath notepad.exe 

# Get the specific process object and assign to a variable
($NotepadProcess = Get-Process -Name Notepad)
```

> 2. Which get-process property will show a process started ...

Review these results

```
# Get all the specific process object data
$NotepadProcess | Get-Member


# Get only the properties of the specific object
Get-Content -Path variable:\NotepadProcess | Format-List -Force


Get-Content -Path variable:\NotepadProcess | Select-Object -Property *
```

> 2... and is this the same to use with New-Timespan ?

Not directly. You can only use the .StartTime property as part of the New-TimeSpan cmdlet, if stored in a variable, because the .ExitTime is not populated while the process is running and obviously the .ExitTime is not available when the process is not running.

Example

```
# Start a specific process
Start-Process -FilePath notepad.exe 

# Get the specific process object and assign to a variable
($NotepadProcess = Get-Process -Name Notepad)

# Get the specific process start time properties
$NotepadProcess.StartTime
$NotepadProcess.WaitForExit() # At this point the process / object is gone
$NotepadProcess.HasExited
$NotepadProcess.ExitCode
$NotepadProcess.ExitTime
```

> 3. How can I use get help to see these variables for Get-Process...

You can only get help from static help files for cmdlet/functions,

```
# Get parameters, examples, full and Online help for a cmdlet or function
(Get-Command -Name Get-Process).Parameters
Get-help -Name Get-Process -Examples
Get-help -Name Get-Process -Full
Get-help -Name Get-Process -Online
```

... not variables created on the fly.

You look up variable info by the name you created it as of via the PSDrive, 
variable:\ as shown previously

> 3...and New-Timespan?

```
(Get-Command -Name New-TimeSpan).Parameters
Get-help -Name New-TimeSpan -Examples
Get-help -Name New-TimeSpan -Full
Get-help -Name New-TimeSpan -Online
```

No, only the .StartTime is usable for the New-TimeSpan if stored in a variable, as other time related properties are empty while running and gone when the process terminates. You have to use another date variable to hold starttime and another variable to create and hold endtime.

For example:

```
# Start a specific process
Start-Process -FilePath notepad.exe 

# Get the specific process object and assign to a variable
($NotepadProcess = Get-Process -Name Notepad)

# Get the specific process start time properties
($StartTime = $NotepadProcess.StartTime)
$NotepadProcess.WaitForExit()
($EndTime = (Get-Date).DateTime)
($ElaspedTime = New-TimeSpan -Start $StartTime -End $EndTime)
```

Results

```
Start-Process -FilePath notepad.exe 

($NotepadProcess = Get-Process -Name Notepad)

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
231      14     3344      17092       0.09   9840   1 notepad



($StartTime = $NotepadProcess.StartTime)

Friday, 9 February, 2018 22:17:25


$NotepadProcess.WaitForExit()

($EndTime = (Get-Date).DateTime)
Friday, 9 February, 2018 22:17:42

($ElaspedTime = New-TimeSpan -Start $StartTime -End $EndTime)

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 16
Milliseconds      : 193
Ticks             : 161932573
TotalDays         : 0.000187421959490741
TotalHours        : 0.00449812702777778
TotalMinutes      : 0.269887621666667
TotalSeconds      : 16.1932573
TotalMilliseconds : 16193.2573
```

As for ...

> I would still treat variables like they were in Linux like this command

You are setting yourself up for unnecessary stress, strain and confusion with this thought process. You have to think and breath the PowerShell way in order to really understand it and then use your previous experience to try and mix and match when / where possible..

Again, this...

> $promem = Get-Process | Get-Member"...
>   ...but this $promem is also considered an object ye?

...is wrong. At least the way you have it/ been thinking about it, because again, this is a collection. Not a single object as shown using the $NotepadProcess above.

As for...

> but my question was how to have that command output a true or false statement when the command finishes

Get-Process will never fail as it's only purpose is to list what is running. Sure other things can fail, but that is what validation / error handling is for:

```
If..Then
Try..Catch
Case Select
etc...
```

Just use your favorite search engine to look up PowerShell error handling.

All that being said. You really need to hammer at your instructor to make sure you have clarity on the course content and goals. Well, that and read the help files and the about_XXX content either directly in PowerShell or via the MS PowerShell Docs site.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell